# Junit for QueryDsl

Tags: mockito, querydsl

I'm trying to write a test case for a  query dsl, I'm getting null pointer exception when I run the test case

Dsl Class

```
 QMyClass myClass= QMyClass.myClass;

                    queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);

                    JPAQuery<?> from = queryFactory.from(myClass);
                    JPAQuery<?> where = from
                            .where(prepdicates);
                    orderBy(orderSpecifier).offset(sortOrder.getOffset())
                            .limit(sortOrder.getPageSize());

**Junit test case:**

import javax.inject.Provider;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslRepositorySupport;

import com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;
import com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLTemplates;
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery;
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyClass{


    @Mock
    QueryDslRepositorySupport queryDslRepositorySupport;

    @Mock
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Mock
    JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;
    @Mock
    JPAQuery step1;

    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass;




    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

         Provider<EntityManager> provider = new Provider<EntityManager>() {
             @Override
             public EntityManager get() {
                 return entityManager;
             }
         };

         queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(JPQLTemplates.DEFAULT, provider);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() throws Exception {
        QMyClass class= Mockito.mock(QMyClass.class);

        Mockito.when(queryFactory.from(class)).thenReturn(step1);
        Predicate step2 = Mockito.mock(Predicate.class);
        Mockito.when(step1.where(step2)).thenReturn(step1);
        OrderSpecifier step3 = Mockito.mock(OrderSpecifier.class);
        Mockito.when(step1.orderBy(step3)).thenReturn(step1);
        Mockito.when(step1.offset(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(step1);
        Mockito.when(step1.limit(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(step1);

        myClass.method("");
    }
}
```

When I run this test case I'm getting null pointer exception at line number 2 in sampleTest() method. I googled but did't find any article for this, not sure why this NE, even after mocking the queryfacotry

Here is the trace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.querydsl.core.DefaultQueryMetadata.addJoin(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:154)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.QueryMixin.from(QueryMixin.java:163)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPAQueryBase.from(JPAQueryBase.java:77)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory.from(JPAQueryFactory.java:116)
    at
```

Comment: Please add a [mre], with the information what you use to run the test (runner, extension, rule ...), the complete class under test (especially where the things you are planing to mock are coming from), the version of your junit & mocktio libraries and the full stacktrace. -- For now I can only say that you should not overwrite queryFactory if you want it to be a mock.

Comment: You didnt post the complete stacktrace and didnt post the code for myClass#method. Also your code cant compile as `class` is a keyword and can not be used as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, your problem is that you do not use a mock, but the real object instead.

Remove the queryFactory initialisation from your setup method.

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

         Provider<EntityManager> provider = new Provider<EntityManager>() {
             @Override
             public EntityManager get() {
                 return entityManager;
             }
         };

         // remove this line
         // queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(JPQLTemplates.DEFAULT, provider);

    }
```

---

Also you need to change your **implementation**, you can not use
`queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);` inside your code, as it can not be mocked.

What you could do instead is having a method that returns the JPAQueryFactory,
either from another class - which you can mock -
or in the same method, then you would need to spy on your class instead.

As you didnt add the code for the class you want to test (MyClass - hopefully a different one from the identical named UnitTest?), another possibility would be that you try to use Field or Constructor Injection (as indicated by the use of your annotations), but then there should not be an object creation for the JPAQueryFactory in your code at all.

---

This also seems to be wrong:
You should inject mocks into your class under test, not in your UnitTest class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyClass{

    ...

    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass;
```